# Program to output the max and min

Tags: java, for-loop, io, max, min

//Basically in this program you have to ask the user for a terminating value and then a set of numbers. When you put in your terminating number, the program ends. You then output the max and min of the numbers you entered BUT NOT the terminating value. I'm looking for help with my for statement because the loop only goes twice. Only IO please.

```
public class smalllargest {     
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter any number, then re-enter that number when you wish to be done.");
        int t = IO.readInt();
        System.out.println("Enter your set of numbers");
        int s = IO.readInt();
        int max = s;
        int min = s;
        for(int i = 0; i!=t; i++) {
            int n = IO.readInt();
            if(n > max) {
                max = n ;
            }
            if(n< max) {
                min = n;
            }
            if(n == t){
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("max:");
            IO.outputIntAnswer(max);
            System.out.println("min:");
            IO.outputIntAnswer(min);
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about using a while loop instead of for,

```
while(s!=t) {
 s = IO.readInt();
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop should be

```
while (s !=t )
```

and the println's should come after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

For what I see in this code the first inserted number is not used as a termination value.

```
for(int i = 0; i!=t; i++)
```

Will run t times before exiting.

If you want t to be the termination value instead of using a for loop you could use a while.

Not a Java expert, but something like:

```
int t = IO.readInt();    
int s = t + 1; // just to be sure s != t
int min = 999999999;
int max = 0;
System.out.println("Enter your set of numbers");
while (s != t) {
  int s = IO.readInt();
  if (s != t) { // to exclude t from the output
    if (min > s) min = s;
    if (max < s) max = s;
  }
}

System.out.println("max: ");
IO.outputIntAnswer(max);
System.out.println("Min: ");
IO.outputIntAnswer(min);
```

Once again, I'm not a Java programmer so you should check my code for syntax errors, but it should give you an idea of how to do it.